# Raspberry pi won't boot after unclean power down

Tags: boot, power, fsck

I am new to Raspberry Pi exchange, looks like I'm having a micro SD corruption problem.

I was about to plug a USB webcam into my Raspberry Pi 3 model b and I accidentally stepped in the power button!

I tried to boot my Raspberry pi again but at boot it just stopped at end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179, 7)

I don't want to reinstall the operating system and opencv either!
Please Advice! I am in urgent need of fixing this! Thank you!

Comment: If you have accidentally turn of the power without a proper "shutdown" then it's a possibility that the SD card is corrupt. There is a possibility that fsck could repair it, see here : https://raymii.org/s/blog/Broken_Corrupted_Raspberry_Pi_SD_Card.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy the data you need from the card.
Flash a new image of Raspbian or whatever suits you.

For the OpenCV part this guy got you covered:
[OpenCV for the Pi](https://github.com/jabelone/OpenCV-for-Pi)

Comment: Comments are not for extanded discussions. Please use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65422/discussion-on-answer-by-amadeusxnet-raspberry-pi-wont-boot) for such things.